# How to plot multiple normal distributions in 1 figure in R

Tags: r, plot

I have a data that gives the mean
and SD:

```
#info mean sd
info1 20.84 4.56
info2 29.18 5.41
info3 38.90 6.22
```

Actually there are more than 100 lines of this.
How can I plot normal distributions for each one of the line in *one* figure 
given the above data?

Comment: I assumed you wanted some way to differentiate between each row of data, I chose linetype, but you can also use colour, or a combination of the two. Or if you don't need to differentiate between density estimates, then ignore that part all together :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on how large N truly gets, you may want to split this up over a set of multiple charts. But, here's the basic approach. First, you need to generate some random data according to your mean and sd. I chose 1000 random points, you can adjust as necessary. Next, set up a blank plot with the appropriate dimensions, then use `lines` and `density` to add the data. I used a for loop because it provided a nice way to specify the linetype for each data point. Finally, add a legend at the end:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "info mean sd
info1 20.84 4.56
info2 29.18 5.41
info3 38.90 6.22
", header = TRUE)

densities <- apply(dat[, -1], 1, function(x) rnorm(n = 1000, mean = x[1], sd = x[2]))
colnames(densities) <- dat$info

plot(0, type = "n", xlim = c(min(densities), max(densities)), ylim = c(0, .2))
for (d in 1:ncol(densities)){
  lines(density(densities[, d]), lty = d)
}
legend("topright", legend=colnames(densities), lty=1:ncol(densities))
```

[image]

Or, use ggplot2 which can have lots of benefits, namely it will specify reasonable xlim and ylim values for you automagically, and do sensible things with the legend without much fuss.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#Put into long format
densities.m <- melt(densities)
#Plot
ggplot(densities.m, aes(value, linetype = Var2)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

Comment: Why go through the process of generating random data so you can use a density estimate when you could just plot the actual densities without generating data?

Comment: @Dason - my initial pass at the question was that the OP wanted a scatterplot of the points, but then realized he probably wanted the density curves...you are right though - not necessary if the end goal is simply the make the density curves. Tyler's answer shows how to use `dnorm` directly.

Comment: where does var2 come from? I can't see to make this work even using factor(var2), because then it complains that aes is not the same length. Also what is 'value'?

Comment: @user4050 - I just ran the example code and everything worked...you get `var2` and `value` once you `melt()` the data. I guess make sure you have `reshape2` and `ggplot2` loaded?

Answer (score 6):

Again a dollar short and a day late.  Chase has a very thorough response.  Here's my crack at it:

```
dat <- read.table(text="info  mean  sd
info1 20.84 4.56
info2 29.18 5.41
info3 38.90 6.22", header=T)

dat <- transform(dat, lower= mean-3*sd, upper= mean+3*sd)

plot(x=c(min(dat$lower)-2, max(dat$upper)+2), y=c(0, .25), ylab="", 
    xlim=c(min(dat$lower)-2, max(dat$upper)+2), xlab="", 
    axes=FALSE, xaxs = "i", type="n")
box()

FUN <- function(rownum) {
    par(new=TRUE)
    curve(dnorm(x,dat[rownum, 2], dat[rownum, 3]),
        xlim=c(c(min(dat$lower)-2, max(dat$upper)+2)), 
        ylim=c(0, .22),
        ylab="", xlab="")
}

lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), function(i) FUN(i))
```

[image]